# How to pull into content from XML using AMPscript?

Tags: email, marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a data extension in ExactTarget where in one of the fields we have XML code from where I have to extract specific info to print it out in an email newsletter.

E.g.:

```
FirstName: James
Last Name: Smith
XML: <root><Item count='97' member_id='123456' priority='1' type='CarIDrive' ></Item><Item count='97' member_id='7890123' priority='2' type='PlacesILike' ></Item><Item count='69' member_id='765432378' priority='3' type='GasPerMile' ></Item></root>
```

So the excel data files has the above headers: FirstName LastName XML

In the HTML email we will have a couple of places where the copy will be populated dynamically through AMPscript. e.g. FirstName, LastName, CarIDrive, PlacesILike and GasPerMile.

How can I assign variables to CarIDrive, PlacesILike and GasPerMile from the XML code from the data extension so I can call these variables in my HTML email?

Thanks,
Vic

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`BuildRowSetFromXML(S1,S2,B1)`](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/)

Given the XML

```
<root>
  <Item count='97' member_id='123456' priority='1' type='CarIDrive' ></Item>
  <Item count='97' member_id='7890123' priority='2' type='PlacesILike' ></Item>
  <Item count='69' member_id='765432378' priority='3' type='GasPerMile' ></Item>
</root>
```

You would do this:

```
set @rowset = BuildRowsetFromXml(@xml, "//Item", 1)
```

Resulting in the rowset:

```
Value    XML    member_id_att   priority_att  type_att
 ""      ""     123456          1             CarIDrive
 ""      ""     7890123         1             PlacesILike
 ""      ""     765432378       1             GasPerMile
```

Access the attributes like normal, or loop through etc:

```
set @member_id = Field(Row(@rowset, 1), 'member_id_att')
```

Comment: I saw this @Kelly in the documentation:<br/>
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromXML<br/><br/>The question is what should I do after. Can you help?

Comment: Correct - that should be what you want to do.

Comment: There is a link to that in the function name.

Comment: so you're saying if I create this variable e.g. [at]member_id_att and assign it Set [at]member_id_att = [member_id_att] will spit out 123456 for the lookuprow #1?

Comment: also the XML is in the data file in the fields from the column called XML. If I retrieve only the value on that column it's going to be the whole XML code.

Comment: It's not per subscriber?

Comment: yes @Kelly, every subscriber has a different xml code in that data field.

Comment: Then yes - you would pull in the full XML. If that's not all required, you may need to redo your data there a bit.  The idea behind `BuildRowsetFromXML()` is that it takes a full XML string, and makes it into a rowset as if you pulled it from a data extension.  Does that make sense?